# WebRTC browser-to-browser

Tags: html, webrtc, p2p

I am trying to use WebRTC to implement browser to browser communication.

I want to allow communication between two browsers running on two different computers in the same LAN.

Can somebody confirm is this possible and if so, how.

I tried looking up the demos and seems they all have examples for application running in the same page. But I would like to connect to a peer computer using some IP address.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved your problem using https://github.com/feross/simple-peer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a Peer to peer connection using PEERJS. PeerJS simplifies WebRTC peer-to-peer data, video. PeerJS wraps the browser's WebRTC implementation to provide a complete, configurable, and easy-to-use peer-to-peer connection API within a LAN Network. [PEERJS](http://peerjs.com/)